# awk : Compare 2 files , find missing fields and append the complete line

Tags: awk

I have two files Temp.txt and Permanent.txt.

1. Temp.txt has 6 fields.
2. Permanent.txt has an extra 7th field when compared to temp.txt.
3. Field 3 in both files have ip adresss.

If an IP address in **Temp.txt** is not present in **Permanent.txt**, then append that particular whole line of **Temp.txt** to the end of **Permanent.txt**.

Also after appending, i need the **field 7** of the appended line to  be set as **1**.

temp.txt:

```
5 , 5 , 123.123.123.123 , ITALY , Open_Source , mango
5 , 5 , 222.222.222.222 , China , Open_Source , test1
5 , 5 , 233.233.233.233 , China , Open_Source , test2
5 , 5 , 255.255.255.255 , INDIA , Open_Source , apple
```

permanent.txt

```
1 , 2 , 111.111.111.111 , China , Open_Source , test8 , 4
5 , 5 , 222.222.222.222 , China , Open_Source , test1 , 4
5 , 5 , 233.233.233.233 , China , Open_Source , test2 , 4
9 , 3 , 244.244.244.244 , China , Open_Source , test1 , 4
```

I want to **modifiy** the permanent.txt and contents of the **modified permanent.txt** is as follows:

```
1 , 2 , 111.111.111.111 , China , Open_Source , test8 , 4
5 , 5 , 222.222.222.222 , China , Open_Source , test1 , 4
5 , 5 , 233.233.233.233 , China , Open_Source , test2 , 4
9 , 3 , 244.244.244.244 , China , Open_Source , test1 , 4
5 , 5 , 123.123.123.123 , ITALY , Open_Source , mango , 1
5 , 5 , 255.255.255.255 , INDIA , Open_Source , apple , 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to do. First read `permanent.txt`, remembering the IPs in it and printing out each line. Then read `temp.txt` and for each IP in it that wasn't in `permanent.txt`, print out that line plus the 1.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
       NR == FNR { seen[$3] = 1; print; next}
       !($3 in seen) { print $0, 1 }' permanent.txt temp.txt
1 , 2 , 111.111.111.111 , China , Open_Source , test8 , 4
5 , 5 , 222.222.222.222 , China , Open_Source , test1 , 4
5 , 5 , 233.233.233.233 , China , Open_Source , test2 , 4
9 , 3 , 244.244.244.244 , China , Open_Source , test1 , 4
5 , 5 , 123.123.123.123 , ITALY , Open_Source , mango,1
5 , 5 , 255.255.255.255 , INDIA , Open_Source , apple,1
```

Comment: Bingo, awk output is fine and it outputs to console as per expected result. But permanent.txt remains unmodified. i need permanent.txt to updated/modified so its contents is same a awk output

Comment: @suhas8989 So redirect the output to a temp file and copy that to the real one afterwards.

Comment: can we use gawk instead of awk, i heard gawk can modify inplace

Comment: @suhas8989 If you're using linux, you're almost certainly using gawk. I've never heard of it supporting sugar like that, though.